# RS485 transceiver bus output error (ADM3065E)

Tags: rs485

What could cause the A and B outputs of a RS485 transceiver, in this case the Analog Devices [ADM3065E](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adm3061e-3062e-3063e-3064e-3065e-3066e-3067e-3068e.pdf), to drive high simultaneously when asserting the driver enable?

**The Situation:**

I have a RS485 bus with five custom boards connected and all are using the ADM3065E transceiver. The bus is physically made up from 120 Ω TE Cheminax twinax cable (about 10' total length) terminated on both ends with 120 Ω resistors. Each board transmits on the bus in sequence based on their pre-configured address starting with address 0. Each transmission consists of 128 bits at a rate of 31.25 Mbps.

We have implemented a TDMA sequence, so a 'missing' board will cause the bus to remain idle for that time slot. In this example, we have boards with addresses 0, 2, 5, 6, and 7, so there are breaks between 0 and 2, and 2 and 5.

We are seeing strange behavior when three boards attempt to access the bus consecutively. In this example, we are seeing the behavior with board #7 since it is the third in a consecutive sequence. The actual address of the boards does not matter, only that it is three consecutive transmissions. If we stagger the addresses such that there never are three transmissions consecutively, we see no errors.

As seen in the screenshot below, the blue trace is the A line, and the yellow trace is the B line. The logic levels of the ADM3065E DE, D, and R are shown as well. As can be seen, #6 finishes its transmission with no errors. The bus voltage levels are as expected. Once #6 de-asserts its driver, #7 asserts its driver ~130 ns later.  Once asserted, both A and B lines drive high even though the D input is a logic high (A should be greater than B). #7 D is driven low around 30 nS after asserting DE, but there is no bus state change (A and B both remain high). This condition remains for about 220 ns until the B line returns to its proper level for the logic level being driven to #7's D input (logic high). Later data bits from #7 (not seen in this screen capture) are transmitted correctly. This behavior at the beginning of #6's transmission is not observed.

We tried the following to rule out software or hardware issues:

- Replaced all five boards with new boards.
- Moved the boards to different physical positions on the bus.
- Disabled the transmission on board #0 and board #2.
- Removed board #0 and #2 thinking maybe there might be some sort of issue with the number of boards physically connected to the bus.
- Assigned other address sequences (i.e. 4, 5, 6). The problem still occurred on the third board.
- Monitored DE on all five boards simultaneously to make sure only one board (#7) was attempting to transmit at the time of this error.

What could cause an RS485 transceiver (ADM3065E) to drive its B output high along with its A output when first asserting its driver? Some sort of internal latch up of its internal H-bridge (I have seen app notes detailing the internal operation on some RS485 transceivers)? Perhaps due to a high bit-rate?

[image]

Comment: Very strange. Try using some other manufacturer's transceiver, e.g., THVD1450.

Comment: What sets the bus voltage when idle? Is there failsafe biasing? Is there a common ground between transceivers or just two data wires? What time you expect to change between transceivers, if datasheet says it can take up to 2000ns to enable/disable them?

Comment: The datasheet is pretty clear on enable time - typ 550ns, max 2us. Time for a different transceiver methinks.

Comment: Well, I agree the ADM3065E has a long enable time, and should probably be changed for a faster part.  Actually, we converted the boards from M-LVDS to RS485 for cable length concerns.  However, the problem does not occur with the other boards, and, the problem occurring on board #7 in this screen shot will not occur if I set it's address to #8 (so it isn't the third consecutive board to transmit).  All of the boards have a ~30nS delay between DE and D driving low and they all work.

Comment: Could you compare similar plot (and post it) of the bus and drivers pins state when the bus switches from consecutive board number 1 to number 2. Would be interesting to see the comparison. And then when you physically switch board number 2 with  3, still problem will remain on the board with consecutive address 3, right?